# Remove all animations from a custom UIAlertView Class iPhone

Tags: iphone, animation, uialertview

I have customized the UIAlertView class. It's working perfectly. I don't want the bounce animations to happen. It should be added to the view without any animations.

At present i have used `[self.layer removeAllAnimations]`.

It has removed the animations except there is a small amount of bounce at the beginning. How can I get rid of this animation? How to avoid the bounce effect completely?

Kindly suggest me an idea to implement this.

Thank You.

Comment: If you see the way a normal UIAlertView pops up,you could see bouncing effect or pop up effect.As i have have customized that i want to prevent the pop up effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case, I used this mathod `setAnimationsEnabled` like

```
[[self class] setAnimationsEnabled:FALSE];
```

but it has a side effect that "after the class(UIAlertView) is showing without bouncing, other window's animation is all stop".